# Your request could be not completed in itunes

Tags: objective-c, itunes

i got one problem when I send url from itunes it giving request could not be found error I am getting , this is url I am sending , in system browser  its open and giving output, but from iphone its not given,

http://itunes.apple.com/us/video/hips-dont-lie-feat-wyclef-jean/id205700602?uo

please help me, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`http://itunes.apple.com/us/video/hips-dont-lie-feat-wyclef-jean/id262804798?uo=4`